# XSLT 1.0 decimal number formatting for zero decimals and non zero decimals

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

hi i have set of inputs as below

```
22.00
25.25
25.56
56.15
85
```

and the output to be

```
22
25.25
25.56
56.15
85
```

any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: And if the input is `1.20`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k i need it as 1.20, if the input is 1.00 then i need output as 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to deduce the rule from your examples. Applying the `number()` function to the input will produce the results you show - perhaps that is what you want.

---

### Added:

If you want the input of `1.20` to be preserved as `1.20`, then you can test for the value of `input mod 1` to separate the two cases - see the demo at: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncnu9B7

Comment: my question is if i have only zeros after decimals then that zeros are not in need, so the integer part is more than enough to print, but if it has decimal places like.25 .30 .15, then those places to be included, now go back to the question once, you will find the clarity now @michael.hor257k

as of now my code looks like 
```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(string(.)), '##0.00')"/>
```
since it returns 1.00 as 1.00 itself, but my requirement is, the output should be 1 here